# Documentation for Adobe Flash CS4?

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, flash-cs3

Adobe Flash CS4 contains no documentation at all; it simply redirects to the [online docs.](http://probertson.com/articles/2008/10/14/flash-player-10-flash-cs4-documentation/) Since I own the older Flash CS3 I was wondering if I could use the older HTML files with the newer IDE, by changing some XML file within the Flash CS4 directory on my C: drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash CS4 contains the entire standard set of documentation. It just defaults to using the online docs whenever you have a network connection available. Offline docs are stored at:

- WIN: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Help\en_US\Flash
- OSX: /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Help/en_US/

Incidentally, to get the IDE to open the offline docs automatically, open: `Window > Extensions > Connections` from the top menu. In the panel that appears, select the menu (the upper right corner of the panel) and choose "Offline options", and check "Keep me offline".

Comment: It opens up the docs in a browser, instead of the Help panel, which is okay. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the old help panel was just an ad-hoc web browser anyway, so you're really better off with the same files shown in a proper browser (so you can search with "/" and F3, etc).

Answer (score 0):

"Flash CS4 contains the entire standard set of documentation...

OSX: /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Help/en_US/"

No it doesn't...

I have absolutely nothing there whatsoever.